# no contents shown when using ILOM Web Interface on SPARC

Tags: ilo, sun, sparc

I accessed to ILOM web interface but the problem there **isn't any content** just Tabs and description as shown Below:

[image: ILOM web interface no content]
**Info:**
SP firmware 3.0.6.1.d
SP firmware build number: 48331
SP filesystem version: 0.1.22
OpenBoot 4.30.4
**Server:**
Sparc T5240
**I try:**
- reset /SP
- reset /SYS
- installation new solaries OS
- Different Browsers Even old of them
so what's missing ?

Best Regards.

Comment: Maybe you need a java plugin in your browser? I would have suggested older browser but you have already tried that. Perhaps Internet Explorer with compatibility modes on/off? I always wonder why it seems impossible to create an ILO web interface that just works and complies with standards :-(

Comment: @wurtel I try with Firefox,Internet Explorer  but even there is no sign of Java